# Expanding instead of scrolling issue on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I'm trying to achieve the following effect: a scrollable (vertically) list of items; each item should be scrollable horizontally if there is such need. I tried the following code:

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="historyViewer" 
                      VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding History}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                          HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneMidBrush}" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Expression}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="resultScroll" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                          HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargePlusFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Result}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is, that if list items are too wide, they extend width of the main scrollviewer instead of becoming scrollable - even though its horizontal alignment is set to stretch.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe it's too late but try to replace `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` with `Disabled` in `ScrollViewer`.